# Neo4j Python driver - is it possible to run `EXPLAIN`?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

Is `EXPLAIN ...` a purely interactive feature, or it is possible to access its outputs from the Python driver? If the latter, how?

And, in general, how does one access programatically all the non-data information returned by a query? (stuff like `Started streaming 25 records after 16 ms and completed after 17 ms.`)

The [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html?highlight=execute#resultsummary) mention `profile` instance variable of the `ResultsSummary` class which is `None` by default. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/7b9248d5d6457b07c0e530e04cf6a22d2b7ef3e1/neo4j/work/summary.py#L62) I still cannot figure out how that field gets populated.

- neo4j community 4.3.2
- neo4j python driver 4.3.4

Comment: Try printing the result if you put EXPLAIN in the query. Haven't tried it so it is interesting to see.

Comment: @jose_bacoy nothing useful gets returned: `data` is all blank (no records, as is consistent with what `EXPLAIN` does in Browser) and metadata fields in `summary` section are blank.

Comment: How about this doc? Will it be useful? https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/summary/ResultSummary.html. Look at ProfiledPlan profile() method.

Comment: Yeah! When you run a query with `PROFILE`, the `profile` dict of `ResultSummary` is non-empty. Thanks for the hint 

Questions remain:

1. What about `EXPLAIN` rather than `PROFILE`?

2. How do we access the query metadata (`Started streaming blah blah`) without invoking `PROFILE`?

Comment: will take a look...